# Git on windows server and GUI client on another machine (AWS)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I was trying to host a git server on a windows instance on AWS(Amazon web services) and then connect to it from another windows instance but using a GUI git client ? 
so is this is possible ? and if it is possible how can it be done ? 
the idea is to put the git server on an instance and use it as a client from another server :)
I hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

*Update* - Apologies, missed the 'gui' bit of your question. Unfortunately git is very command line focussed, there are gui tools but if you're not comfortable with command line, it's definitely worth considering letting somebody else do the hard work, e.g. github. If you're feeling adventurous however read on.

Yes absolutely this is possible - however as somebody else has noted unless you really need the full control from running it yourself it's much less work and risk to use a managed service like github (or coming soon - [an aws equivalent](http://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/))

The first thing I would say (this is as a happy Windows user) is a non gui linux box would be much better for the job, easier to manage, less overhead etc, not to mention git is very solidly in the linux camp and works best with ssh.

The full process is far too in depth to post here, but to help you in your googling a breakdown of the key steps is:

1. Launch the ec2 instance - windows or linux, making sure that:

   - You have an ebs drive provisioned for your repo NOT instance store.
   - Your security group allows in traffic (port 22 for ssh) ONLY from places you want to be able to get your code - if you get it wrong and publish your code - its on you, aws gives you the tools for security, it doesnt do it for you.
   - The OS firewall on your instance also allows the same access (or is turned off)
2. Create the git repository (traditionally as 'shared' and 'bare' for a remote). On a windows box you'll also probably need to install an ssh server.
3. Allow users to access it - again using whatever protocol you go with (i've had the best luck with ssh)
4. Backup, Backup, Backup - Depending on how important your source code is ebs may be 'enough' - though its hidden from you it is stored on multiple drives so you're protected against basic hardware failure. But its not impossible to lose your stuff. Add s3, snapshots and local copies to taste.

Comment: thanks alot for your help actually I achieved the same goal by using an app on the aws market GitLab and I am testing it right now , I can let the users access the repo through a web browser not a git client so it is being tested right now and if it wasn't so good I would try your solutiong :) and thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to host it on AWS and not on github/bitbucket?

Still it can be done, you simply need to install git and set the ssh keys as described **[here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploykeys.html)**

**[Read this for more Information (AWS Initialize Your Git Repository)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your help i will check those links :)